# How to access request object in router function using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI framework, I want to print out the response. For example, in Django:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def install_grandservice(req):
    print(req.body)
```

And in FastAPI:

```
@app.post('/install/grandservice')
async def login():
   //print out req
```

I tried to to like this

```
@app.post('/install/grandservice')
async def login(req):
    print(req.body)
```

But I received this error: **127.0.0.1:52192 - "POST /install/login HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity**

Please help me :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a parameter with a `Request` type in the router function, as

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/install/grandservice')
async def login(request: Request):
    print(request)
    return {"foo": "bar"}
```

This is also covered in the doc, under [***Use the Request object directly***](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#use-the-request-object-directly) section

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example that will print the content of the `Request` for **fastAPI**.
It will print the body of the request as a json (if it is json parsable) otherwise print the raw byte array.

```
async def print_request(request):
    print(f'request header       : {dict(request.headers.items())}' )
    print(f'request query params : {dict(request.query_params.items())}')  
    try : 
        print(f'request json         : {await request.json()}')
    except Exception as err:
        # could not parse json
        print(f'request body         : {await request.body()}')


@app.post("/printREQUEST")
async def create_file(request: Request):
    try:
        await print_request(request)
        return {"status": "OK"}
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(f'could not print REQUEST: {err}')
        return {"status": "ERR"}
```

Comment: defining the function with async will make the application run in a single thread